# Exctract a pattern from a time series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataset, a Pandas dataframe:

```
      Score   min   max               Date
Loc
0    2.757  0.000  2.757 2020-07-04 11:00:00
3    2.723  2.723  0.000 2020-07-04 14:00:00
8    2.724  2.724  0.000 2020-07-04 19:00:00
11   2.752  0.000  2.752 2020-07-04 22:00:00
13   2.742  2.742  0.000 2020-07-05 00:00:00
15   2.781  0.000  2.781 2020-07-05 02:00:00
18   2.758  2.758  0.000 2020-07-05 05:00:00
20   2.865  0.000  2.865 2020-07-05 07:00:00
24   2.832  0.000  2.832 2020-07-05 11:00:00
25   2.779  2.779  0.000 2020-07-05 12:00:00
29   2.775  2.775  0.000 2020-07-05 16:00:00
34   2.954  0.000  2.954 2020-07-05 21:00:00
37   2.886  2.886  0.000 2020-07-06 00:00:00
48   3.101  0.000  3.101 2020-07-06 11:00:00
53   3.012  3.012  0.000 2020-07-06 16:00:00
55   3.068  0.000  3.068 2020-07-06 18:00:00
61   2.970  2.970  0.000 2020-07-07 00:00:00
64   3.058  0.000  3.058 2020-07-07 03:00:00
```

Where:

1. `Score` is a very basic trend, `min` and `max` are the local Minima and Maxima of `Score`.
2. `Loc` is the value on the x axis of that row, and `date` is the that of that row on the chart.

This data, when plotted, looks like that:

[image]

I'm trying to detect the data in the red box from my code, so that i can detect it on other datasets. Basically what I'm looking for is a way to set a definition of that piece of data from my code, so that it can be detected from other data.

Until now, I only managed to mark the local maxima and minima (yellow and red points) on the chart, and i also know how to define that pattern with my own words, I only need to do that from code:

1. Define when a point of minima/maxima is very distant (so it has an higher value) from the previous point of minima/maxima
2. After that, find when the point of local minima and maxima are really near to each other and their values are not very different between each other. In short terms, when a strong increase if followed by a range where the score doesn't go up or down a lot

I hope the question was clear enough, if needed I can give more details.I don't know if it's doable with Numpy or any other library.

Comment: This sounds simple enough using a correlation or cross correlation function. There are implementations in numpy as well as scipy. Try it out and if you have specific issues, then feel free to update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have any example about this particular matter? I'm just getting started to this

Comment: You should provide a minimal working example. I gave you a hint to start looking around so that you can get started. Hopefully, you can find some examples in the numpy or scipy documentation to try out. If you have specific implementation issues or errors then you can open another question, or update this question.

Comment: I found the meaning of cross correlation and such, but i'm not sure it's what i need at this stage. Basically, from what i understood cross correllation mean finding a pattern in a dataset. In this case i have a pattern that i want to search, but i don't know how to define that pattern in terms of code, that's the main problem

Comment: Just use the data from the dataset you have. Then try to match it to your other datasets. Try it out. If you run into a specific problem, then update

Comment: I understand, but there is one thing i don't understand. In this case, i have that pattern in the red box and i want to find similar patterns in other datasets. The problem is that while in this case the Score values ranges between 2 and 3, in other Datasets it may range from 20-30. So don't i need some kind of normalization before?

Comment: Absolutely.... normalized cross correlation will do just that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dynamic time warping (dtw) might work for you. I have used it for something similar. Essentially it allows you to evaluate time series similarity.

Here are the python implementations I know of:

- fastdtw
- dtw
- dtw-python

Here is a decent explanation of how it works

- [Towards Data Science Explanation of DTW](https://towardsdatascience.com/dynamic-time-warping-3933f25fcdd)

You could use it to compare how similar the incoming time series is to the data in your red box.

For example:

```
# Event were looking for
event = np.array([10, 100, 50, 60, 50, 70])

# A matching event occurring
event2 = np.array([0, 7, 12, 4, 11, 100, 51, 62, 53, 72])

# A non matching event
non_event = np.array([0, 5, 10, 5, 10, 20, 30, 20, 11, 9])

distance, path = fastdtw(event, event2)
distance2, path2 = fastdtw(event, non_event)
```

[image: Events]

This will produce a set of indices in which the two time series are matched best.  At this point you can evaluate via which ever method you prefer. I did a crude look at the correlation of the values

```
def event_corr(event,event2, path):
    d = []
    for p in path:
        d.append((event2[p[1]] * event[p[0]])/event[p[0]]**2)

    return np.mean(d)

print("Our event re-occuring is {:0.2f} correlated with our search event.".format(event_corr(event, event2, path)))
print("Our non-event is {:0.2f} correlated with our search event.".format(event_corr(event, non_event, path2)))
```

Produces:

`Our event re-occurring is 0.85 correlated with our search event.`

`Our non-event is 0.45 correlated with our search event.`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. This is very interesting! The only problem i have is that i somehow need to normalize this data, for the following reason: the pattern might be exactly the same as the one i attached on my question, but with different values. So, in this case the values in the pattern range from 2 to 3; but what happens when the  shape of the pattern is the same but the values are from 13 to 15, for example?

Comment: Depending on what your other data is like when its not an event, you could normalize by dividing the data sets by their change over some time period ( e.g. data / (max - min) ) before applying dtw.

Comment: Indeed, normalizing by Variation might be a good solutio, even though it can still be a little bit inaccurate in some cases, so i want to see if there is something even more accurate. Let me make some research on DTM to see if it can work with my case. By the way, have you ever used Stumpy? It was suggested to me https://pypi.org/project/stumpy/

Comment: Sounds like this cool work; i think it depends a lot on how i normalize my data, but it can be a viable way. I'll test it with DTW to see what i got, i'll make another question if i should have any problem. Thank you really a lot!

Comment: One more thing: suppose there is pattern A, which is the pattern in the red box for example. Then i have another dataset. I want to find pattern A in the dataset B, so since Dataset B is big, pattern A will be found only in some parts of the datasets, so i only need to extract from Dataset B the "regions"  where pattern A is found; is it possible?

Comment: To make it short and simple, in your example you are comparing two patterns that have the same length. In my case, i have a pattern and another dataset, i want to get from the dataset only the "regions" where the pattern is found, so for example from DATE X to DATE Y the pattern was found